# Algorithm to determine the possibility of selecting 1 unique element from n arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Have a little bit of a nut to crack. I have the brute force implementation of the algorithm, which is not really that hard, but obviously I want something more efficient.

**The problem is as follows:**

Imagine you have *n* arrays, each filled with some values between *1* and *n*. What I need is to determine whether it's possible to select one element from each of those arrays, such that I select each element from *1* to *n* exactly one time. A little example: suppose `n = 4` and we have these `n` arrays:

```
[1,2,3,4]
[1,3]
[2,4]
[3,4]
```

This combination of arrays would pass the algorithm, since it is possible to (for example) select 1, 3, 2, 4 from each array respectively. Another possibility would be 2, 1, 4, 3.
A counter example would be:

```
[1,2,3]
[3]
[3,4]
[3,4]
```

Here you clearly see that these input arrays wouldn't pass the algorithm. There is no way that it is possible to select 1 element from each array in such a way that each element is selected once.

As I said, the brute force approach is not that complicated, but I want something more efficient, without going through all possible permutations until I found one that passes the criteria.

Comment: What language are you programming in? Would be better to tag your question with the appropriate language so you receive more directed help!

Comment: What about, as for an "easier" implementation, but also bruteforce, a simple binary tree. the first `n/2`will be checked by half of the input that should pass the test, and the other half by the other input half! Just a suggestion!

Comment: few questions: 1- are numbers always in this range `1 <= x <= n`? 2- are arrays sorted?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary yes and yes. So if we have 3 arrays, the numbers that could be in each are always 1,2,3. 5 arrays? 1,2,3,4,5 could be in all. And yes, they will be sorted within the array.

Comment: if `k` numbers appear in `k - 1` places or less, it will be impossible to select unique elements. for example if 3 numbers appear in only 2 places or in your second example two numbers `1,2` appear in one place.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary: still brute-force ish... for every combination of numbers in each array, I would have to count how many times they occur in all arrays. Imagine 8 arrays, each of them rather filled up with numbers. I would have to select each combination of 2 numbers, each combination of 3, each of 4 and so on. Not very efficient.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This problem could be reduced to [Maximum Bipartite Matching](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-bipartite-matching/), which could be solved by [Ford-Fulkerson Algorithm for Maximum Flow Problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ford-fulkerson-algorithm-for-maximum-flow-problem/):

Let's create a flow graph of `2*n` nodes, with the first set of `n` nodes represent the array, while the next set of `n` nodes represent values. So there will be an edge from node `i` in the first set to node `j` in the second set if and only if inside array `i`, there contains value `j`. The capacity for this edge should be 1, which represent that you can only choose one from each array.

After forming this graph, apply the classic algorithm to find the answer.

For the example in the question:

```
[1,2,3,4]
[1,3]
[2,4]
[3,4]
```

We can form this graph

[image]

The white nodes represent arrays, while the green nodes represent values.

Comment: I was actually thinking about "would this be a bipartite thing" earlier on. Definitely good suggestion. Got an implementation of that from another algorithm course I did. I'll give it a whirl, thanks!

Comment: Can you please draw an example of the flow chart? I don't see it :)

Comment: Works just fine. Thank you very much.